# Substitute maple syrup with regular syrup for baking?

Tags: baking, substitutions, maple-syrup

I'm trying to create a 'sticky apple pecan cake', the recipe calls for Maple Syrup. Sadly that's really hard to get here.

I do have a full bottle of 'regular' syrup in my cabinet, could I use that instead? It's thicker than maple syrup but the sweetness is about the same to me.

This is the recipe:

> INGREDIENTS
>   1½ cups of cooking oil
>   2 cups sugar
>   4 Eggs
>   3 cups of flour
>   1 tsp baking soda
>   ½ tsp cinnamon
>   1 tsp salt
>   2 tsps vanilla
>   3½ cups Granny Smith apples (approximately 3-4 apples), peeled and chopped
>   1 cup of chopped pecans
>
> Caramel Glaze
>   ¾ cups butter (1½ sticks)
>   1 cup light brown sugar
>   ¼ cup milk
>   1 tsp vanilla

Comment: There is no maple or regular syrup in this recipe.

Comment: Jane, welcome! I just formatted your post for you, but I can't find maple syrup in your ingredient list. Could you please [edit] your post and fix this?

Comment: Are you following [Chris Scheuer's recipe for Sticky Apple Pecan Cake](http://thecafesucrefarine.com/2014/10/sticky-apple-pecan-cake/)? What do you mean by 'regular' syrup? It is corn syrup (light or dark) or pancake syrup?

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely use regular (if you mean regular is in Betty Crocker and the like) as a replacement for Maple Syrup in this recipe. The flavor won't be quite as nice because you'll be missing the maple flavor, but it will definitely have the sweetness you want.

Comment: I don't agree. Betty Crocker is fructose and maple syrup is sucrose. I am not sure they will heat in the same way.